# How can I prevent my functional component from re-rendering with React memo or React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

When `hiddenLogo` changes value, the component is re-rendered. I want this component to **never** re-render, even if its props change. With a class component I could do this by implementing sCU like so:

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
  return false;
}
```

But is there a way to do with with React hooks/React memo?

Here's what my component looks like:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import ConnectedSpringLogo from '../../containers/ConnectedSpringLogo';

import { Wrapper, InnerWrapper } from './styles';
import TitleBar from '../../components/TitleBar';

const propTypes = {
  showLogo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  hideLogo: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  hiddenLogo: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

const Splash = ({ showLogo, hideLogo, hiddenLogo }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (hiddenLogo) {
      console.log('Logo has been hidden');
    }
    else {
      showLogo();

      setTimeout(() => {
        hideLogo();
      }, 5000);
    }
  }, [hiddenLogo]);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <TitleBar />
      <InnerWrapper>
        <ConnectedSpringLogo size="100" />
      </InnerWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};

Splash.propTypes = propTypes;

export default Splash;
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

As G.aziz said, React.memo functions similarly to pure component. However, you can also adjust its behavior by passing it a function which defines what counts as equal. Basically, this function is shouldComponentUpdate, except you return true if you want it to **not** render.

```
const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => true;

const MyComponent = React.memo(props => {
  return /*whatever jsx you like */
}, areEqual);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: How can we perform a deep comparison of props?

Comment: React.memo only compare newProps and oldProps, how can we compare newState and oldState to decide when to re-render?

Comment: @QuocVanTang the useState hook will do its own check to make sure the value changed, and skip the render if it did not. Other than that, you can't prevent a rerender when setting state in a functional component. Depending on what your component does, you can use useMemo or useCallback to skip some calculations in the render.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I suppose if we have the oldState is { xyz: 1 }, then we set the newState to it as the equal value { xyz: 1} (new reference object but equal as deep compare). For now, it still re-render because react hooks do shallow compare so I want to skip the re-render for this case

Comment: Regarding `React.memo`, the docs say, "This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs." (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).
Does anyone know more about what bugs can occur?

Comment: I think this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61547432/839847) is a pretty good discussion of the potential costs of using `React.memo` - although the discussion is around performance costs, not potential bugs.

Comment: I have a similar problem, can I get a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176305/changing-props-state-using-api-causes-infinite-loop/72186468#72186468

Answer (score 18):

[React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) is same thing as [React.PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#be-careful-when-using-render-props-with-reactpurecomponent)

You can use it when you don't want to update a component that you think is static so, Same thing as `PureCompoment`.

**For class Components:**

```
class MyComponents extends React.PureCompoment {}
```

**For function Components:**

```
const Mycomponents = React.memo(props => {
  return <div> No updates on this component when rendering </div>;
});
```

So it's just creating a component with `React.memo`

> To verify that your component doesn't render you can just
>   activate `HightlightUpdates` in react `extension` and check your `components reaction` on
>   `rendering`

Comment: React.memo will re-render the component when its props change. My question is how can I make my component *never* re-render even if props change, and **without** using a class.

Comment: Rewrite the second parameter of memo to () => true;

Answer (score 11):

We can use [memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) for prevent render in function components for optimization goal only. According React document:

> This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

According to react documentation:- [https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html][1]

> React. memo is a higher order component. If your component renders the
> same result given the same props, you can wrap it in a call to React.
> memo for a performance boost in some cases by memoizing the result.
> This means that React will skip rendering the component, and reuse the
> last rendered result.

For practical understanding I came across these two videos they are very good if you wanna clear concepts also, better to watch so it'll save your time.

*Disclaimer:-* This is not my YouTube channel.

- https://youtu.be/qySZIzZvZOY [ useMemo hook]
- https://youtu.be/7TaBhrnPH78 [class based component]