# functional component rerender on state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've implemented a window resize event on initial component load. The event detects the window inner width and saves the value in a hook. Based on the width hook there is a second useEffect function, triggered on width change:

```
export const AppRouter = (props) => {

    const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleResize = () => setWidth(window.innerWidth);
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        setAppLayoutForViewportWidth();
    }, [width]);
}
```

Now to the unexpected behavior: the entire component rerenders on width hook change and not only the useEffect based on the width hook.

Can someone name the reason, why the entire component rerenders? Can I only rerender the width-based useEffect?

Comment: what does `setAppLayoutForViewportWidth` do?

Comment: the function only calls imported helper functions based on the window.innerWidth

Comment: I don't get a question but it works as expected. When width was changed, the whole component re-renders, because component re-renders every time, when state changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Why?**

**setState({})** always **forces to re-render**. (*unless you return false in: shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState)*) You can check this by putting a console log in

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    console.log("Component did update")
}
```

Your `setWidth(window.innerWidth);`will change state due to it being: `useState(window.innerWidth);` which will force a rerender.

### **How to prevent it:**

If you want to control when it rerenders, create a logic in `shouldComponentUpdate` to return false when you want to prevent rerender.

**If you are in a functional component** have a  look at React.Memo. More on that in this thread: [How can I prevent my functional component from re-rendering with React memo or React hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54946933/how-can-i-prevent-my-functional-component-from-re-rendering-with-react-memo-or-r)

> React.Memo functions similarly to pure component. However, you can
>   also adjust its behavior by passing it a function which defines what
>   counts as equal. Basically, this function is shouldComponentUpdate,
>   except you return true if you want it to not render.
>
> ```
> const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => true;
>
> const MyComponent = React.memo(props => {
>   return /*whatever jsx you like */
> }, areEqual);
> ```

Comment: This helps me a lot! Thanks for your nicely structured answer

Comment: Happy it could help! Please accept if it answers your question to close the thread :)