# select all results to an infinite loop update error in react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

[Playground Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-with-hooks-forked-dp72w?file=/src/table.js)
Just setup custom hooks for react-table to enable custom search and select all rows.
Then  this happens when I select a single row, plus the select All option does not seem to work as expected. [image]

Answer (score 0):

From the console logs, it seems that React is falling into infinite re-render cycle. I am not an expert with React Hooks. Please excuse me if I am pointing out something that you have tried for sure.

Please take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54946933/how-can-i-prevent-my-functional-component-from-re-rendering-with-react-memo-or-r)

In other words, you can try implementing Hooks equivalent of `shouldComponentUpdate` and check what all properties are changing. That should give you some direction on how to sort this out.