# React: Is using React.Memo in for all components a good way

Tags: reactjs

React gives a way to memoize the components using `React.memo` which actually stops the component re-render if there is no change in props.

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

interface ComponentNameProps {

}
const ComponentName:React.FC<ComponentNameProps> = props => {
    const {} = props;
    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default memo(ComponentName)
```

Do we put all our component into `memo`, will it be a good practise?

Comment: `React.memo` is used to memoize heavy calculations. I don't think what you are trying to do is **good practice**.

Comment: This might be useful, checkout this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53074551/when-should-you-not-use-react-memo

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you use `React.memo`, everytime you use the component react is gonna run a compare function to see if the props have changed; so if redeclaring your function is less expensive, then you are hurting the performance, rather than improving it. so it's a tradeoff that sometimes is worth making, but not for every component.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not a good practice.
In fact, overusing useMemo can hurt your application more (performance-wise) than the re-renders.

Please use wisely and with caution.

Read more about it [here.](https://medium.com/swlh/should-you-use-usememo-in-react-a-benchmarked-analysis-159faf6609b7)

Comment: `useMemo` is not the same thing as `React.memo`. Also the performance considerations are [quite different](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63405621/4961158).