# Why is it necessary to keep function components pure if they aren't even memoized by default?

Tags: reactjs

According to [the React docs](https://react.dev/learn/keeping-components-pure), React assumes that every component you write is a pure function.

But then there's the [memo](https://react.dev/reference/react/memo) function.

Doesn't the existence of that function imply that components will be re-rendered by default anyway, even if they were given the same props? To me that sounds like React *does not* rely on function components being pure by default.

For example, if I had some impure function component that relied on uncontrolled global variables, what problems would that pose realistically? Unless I wrap it in the `memo` function, React will re-render it anyway even when given the same props.

I'm asking this because there are special edge cases where it's not always convenient to keep your functional components truly pure (using `localStorage` outside of `useEffect`, mutable global variables, etc.) and it would help to know what the actual consequences of impure components are.

Comment: Don't program against the implementation, program against the specification. Except if you enjoy looking for hard to diagnose bugs when you update that library. Also the site lists lots of good reasons for purity.

Comment: "*That sounds like React does not rely on function components being pure*" - sure, React doesn't care what your function components do. It just renders them, and provides a context for the hooks. But *you* should care: if your components do different things depending on when (or in what order) they are rendered, you're in for a world of pain and suffering.

Comment: Re: "For example, if I had some impure function component that relied on uncontrolled global variables, what problems would that pose realistically? Unless I wrap it in the `memo` function, React will re-render it anyway even when given the same props": Note that React will only re-render the component when its parent component is re-rendered, *not* when the uncontrolled global variables are changed. So you're likely to end up with weird and unpredictable behavior.

Comment: React chooses when to rerender. That is (usually, apart from specific scenarios based on perf) an implementation detail. If your component relies on inputs outside of those that React itself manages (props & state), then you removed the guarantee that the same props/state = same output.  If wondering why then it doesn't memo by default, its partly practical reasons. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74013864/why-arent-all-react-components-wrapped-with-react-memo-by-default/74014100#74014100

Comment: But it's also because memo'ing by default (even if it were practical) wouldn't fix this problem anyway, and would probably make behaviour even *more* unpredictable. For example, if the parent of said "inpure" component updates because of a state change, but the impure components props remain unaltered, it seems like it is less surprising that the output of the child "inpure" component would represent a snapshot of the scope at the time the parent update happened. Its far from ideal, but this behaviour is not unreasonable. It is a you problem to fix for real.