# why react UI Frameworks not use memo or PureComponent by defaults

Tags: reactjs, pure-function, react-memo

- https://github.com/segmentio/evergreen
- https://github.com/kiwicom/orbit
- https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap
- https://github.com/ariakit/ariakit
- https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React

None of these well-known libraries use memo by default, which is inconsistent with the conclusion I got from here [When should you NOT use React memo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53074551/when-should-you-not-use-react-memo), very confused

Comment: could you give an example of where you think they should be using `useMemo`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.