Reduce rerenders with React.memo
I noticed in React that when a component rerenders, its children also rerender even when their input properties did not change. So, in order to reduce rerenders I was reading this tutorial in which they improve this by exporting components as follows
export default React.memo(Child);

In this scenario, the component Child only rerenders when its input properties change!
So my question is, should I always export my components like this? or are there situation in which this approach has side effects?

React.memo is an optimization you should reach for only when you need it.

I suggest to buy the [advance Reac])(https://www.advanced-react.com/) book, which covers all these topics with great details

There are questions very similar to this, here is a good thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53074551/when-should-you-not-use-react-memo

Here is another very good thread: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14463#issuecomment-448829902

Should you add memo everywhere? - from React docs
